# the the step size problem in linespace function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
import numpy as np
z=np.linspace(10,20,5)
z1=np.linspace(10,20,5,endpoint=False)
print(z)
print(z1)
```

The first z is printed out:

```
[ 10.   12.5  15.   17.5  20.]
```

The Second z1 is printed out:

```
[ 10.  12.  14.  16.  18.]
```

My confusion: when it is z, endpoint=True, the number of equally spaced samples to be generated, num=5, that is, five Numbers, so there are four steps, and it's easy to calculate that each step is 2.5.
But: when it is z1, endpoint=False, according to endpoint definition: if the sequence contains 20, it will be rejected, but the sequence is still 5 Numbers, 4 steps long, why is the last number of sequences 18. Not 19. Or other?

Comment: Why should the last number be `19`? Then you'd have 3 evenly spaced regions and one uneven region, seems to go against what `linspace` is used for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to [look at the source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/8e892d4efd8fed1ff499d6c0ec8fba0943bbe3db/numpy/core/function_base.py) here.  This will allow you to walk through what the function is doing, which will give you a better understanding of the output of `linspace`.

---

Two parameters are used to calculate the `step` size: `div` and `delta`.  However, the difference between `endpoint=True`, and `endpoint=False`, is that `div` is equal to `num-1` if `endpoint=True`, and `num` if `endpoint=False`.

```
div = (num - 1) if endpoint else num
```

Here are the other relevent pieces of the source (very slimmed down):

```
delta = stop - start

y = _nx.arange(0, num, dtype=dt)

# ...

if num > 1:
    step = delta / div

# ...

y = y * step

# ...

y += start
```

If we walk through each of these the outputs make a lot more sense.

**`endpoint=True`**:

```
div = num - 1                     # 4
y = _nx.arange(0, num, dtype=dt)  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
delta = 20 - 10                   # 10
step = delta / div                # 2.5
y = y * step                      # [0.0, 2.5, 5.0, 7.5, 10.0]
y += start                        # [10.0, 12.5, 15.0, 17.5, 20.0]
```

**`endpoint=False`**:

```
div = num                         # 5
y = _nx.arange(0, num, dtype=dt)  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
delta = 20 - 10                   # 10
step = delta / div                # 2
y = y * step                      # [0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0]
y += start                        # [10.0, 12.0, 14.0, 16., 18.0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition seems to be that if `endpoint=False` is specified, then the last element of the returned array should be 1 less than the stop value.

Suppose we implement things that way. What does the following `linspace` call return?

```
numpy.linspace(0, 0.5, 5, endpoint=False)
```

Is it going to end at -0.5, counting down? That wouldn't make much sense.

---

`numpy.linspace` always divides the interval from `start` to `stop` into equally-sized chunks, and it always returns an array of length `num`. The difference between `endpoint=True` and `endpoint=False` is that with `endpoint=False`, it makes one extra chunk to compensate for leaving out the right endpoint. The step from 16 to 18 is the same size as the step from 18 to the omitted 20.

Comment: So basically `linspace(a,b,c,endpoint=False) == linspace(a,b,c+1, endpoint=True)[:-1]`?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta: Yes, although it's not implemented that way, and it doesn't make an array with an extra element under the hood (not that doing so would be a significant memory problem or anything).

Comment: Yes I understand that. I just wanted to make sure that for any (valid) values of `a,b,c` that equality returns `True`. Obviously one would be more efficient than the other one.